# Grammar Question: Go to where... or go where

Tags: prepositions

I am confused whether it Is correct and common to say go/come  "to" when the following word is where...

> 1. I will go/come where you suggested
> 2. I will go/come **to** where you suggested.

The reason why I am confused is that I often hear people use "to" when the sentence is something like "**we should go back to where we visited**". I wonder if we treat "go/come back" differently from "go/come".

I also see some people say it both ways.

Is "where" a type of word that can't be used with "to" such as
"There" or "here"?

I couldn't find clear examples or answers in texts, answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> *I will go/come (to) where you suggested*

The preposition "to" is optional.

In a 'fused' relative construction like this, the functions of antecedent and relativised element are combined, or fused, into the single word "where", meaning "some place where".

The variables can thus be represented as "I will go/come to place *x*; you suggested place *x*", where the "to" component is contributed by "where" together with its spatial location function.

The effect of adding the preposition is simply that the "to" component is overtly expressed.